# return the index of doubly-linked list starting from the end (backwards)

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to write undo and redo functions using the doubly-linked list that adds actions(nodes) in the front of the list_1 when *doAction()* is called, stores actions in list_2 when *undo()* is called, and adds the action back to list_1 when *redo()* is called. All elements in both of the lists are added to the front of the list (stack). **I am not allowed to import any additional Java packages.**

public class StringDoublyLinkedList {

```
/**
 * A private class to represent a link in the linked list.
 */
private class Node {
    String value;
    Node next;
    Node prev;

    Node(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
        this.prev = null;
    }
}

private int size = 0;
private Node head = null;
private Node tail = null;
private Node head_2 = null;

/**
 * Add a String to the end of the list.
 *
 * @param value The String to add.
 */
public void add(String value) {
    Node newNode = new Node(value);
    if (this.size == 0) {
        this.head = newNode;
        this.tail = newNode;
    } else {
        this.tail.next = newNode;
        newNode.prev = this.tail;
        this.tail = newNode;
    }
    this.size += 1;
}

/**
 * Get the number of elements in the list.
 *
 * @return The number of elements in the list.
 */
public int size() {
    return this.size;
}

public String get(int index) {
    return this.getNode(index).value;
}

public void remove(int index) {
    Node curr = this.head;
    if (index == 0) {
        this.head = curr.next;
    } else {
        Node node = this.getNode(index - 1);
        node.next = node.next.next;
        if (node.next == tail) {
            this.tail = node;
        }
    }
    this.size -= 1;
}

private Node getNode(int index) {
    Node curr = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    return curr;
}

public boolean undo() {
    Node curr = this.head;
    if (this.size > 0) {
        curr.next.prev = null;
        this.head = curr.next;
        this.head_2 = curr;
    } else if (this.size == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    this.size -= 1;
    return true;
}

public boolean redo() {
    Node curr = this.head;
    Node curr_2 = this.head_2;
    if (this.size > 0) {
        curr_2.next.prev = null;
        this.head_2 = curr_2.next;
        curr.next = this.head;
        this.head.prev = curr;
        this.head = curr;
        } if (this.size == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    this.size += 1;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Record an action.
 *
 * @param action The action to record.
 */
public void doAction(String action) {
    Node newNode = new Node(action);
    if (this.size == 0) {
        this.head = newNode;
        this.tail = newNode;
    } else {
        this.head.prev = newNode;
        newNode.next = this.head;
        this.head = newNode;
    }
    this.size += 1;
}

/**
 * Get the number of actions recorded. Does *not* include actions that were undone.
 *
 * @return The number of actions recorded.
 */
public int getNumActions() { //FIXME
    int count = 1;
    int i;
    for (int i = getNumActions() - 1; i >=0 ; i--) { // second option you have provided
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

/**
 * Get the action at the specified index.
 *
 * Assumes the index < this.getNumActions().
 *
 * @param index The index of the desired action.
 * @return The action (String).
 */

public String getAction(int index) { //FIXME
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
        index = this.size() - index - 1;
    }
    String Actions = this.get(index);
    return Actions;
}

public void print() {
    Node curr = this.head;
    while (curr != null) {
        System.out.print(curr.value);
        System.out.print(", ");
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

This is the test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringDoublyLinkedList actions = new StringDoublyLinkedList();

    actions.doAction("create outline");
    actions.doAction("write introduction paragraph");
    actions.doAction("write paragraph 1a");
    actions.undo();
    actions.doAction("write paragraph 1b");
    actions.doAction("write paragraph 2a");
    actions.undo();
    actions.undo();
    actions.redo();
    actions.doAction("write paragraph 2b");
    actions.doAction("write paragraph 3");
    actions.doAction("write paragraph 4");
    actions.undo();
    actions.doAction("write conclusion paragraph");
    actions.doAction("add expletive about how long this assignment took");
    actions.undo();

    String[] correctActions = {
            "create outline",
            "write introduction paragraph",
            /*"write paragraph 1a",

            "write paragraph 2b",
            "write paragraph 3",
            "write conclusion paragraph" */
    };

    // create a variable for overall correctness
    boolean allCorrect;
    // check the number of actions
    System.out.println(
            "Expected " + Integer.toString(correctActions.length) + " actions " +
                    "and found " + Integer.toString(actions.getNumActions())
    );
    allCorrect = (actions.getNumActions() == correctActions.length);
    // if the number of actions is correct, check each action
    if (allCorrect) {
        for (int i = 0; i < correctActions.length; i++) {
            // get the expected and action actions
            String expectedAction = correctActions[i];
            String actualAction = actions.getAction(i);
            // compare them
            boolean correct = (expectedAction == actualAction);
            // print them out
            System.out.println(
                    "(" + (correct ? "correct" : "incorrect") + ") " +
                            "Action " + Integer.toString(i) + " should be \"" + correctActions[i] + "\" " +
                            "and got \"" + actions.getAction(i) + "\"."
            );
            // update the overall correctness
            allCorrect = (allCorrect && correct);
        }
    }
    // give a summary correct/incorrect judgment
    if (allCorrect) {
        System.out.println("CORRECT!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("INCORRECT!");
    }
}
```

}

The code I wrote in the *getAction()* returns the actions starting from index[0] of the list, but I want it to return the actions backwards (starting from the end of the list).

Using my test case as an example:

(incorrect) Action 0 should be "create outline" and got "write introduction paragraph".

(incorrect) Action 1 should be "write introduction paragraph" and got "create outline".

```
public int getNumActions() { //FIXME
    int count = 1;
    int i;
    for (int i = getNumActions() - 1; i >=0 ; i--) { // error
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public String getAction(int index) { //FIXME
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
        index = this.size() - index - 1;
    }
    String Actions = this.get(index);
    return Actions;
}
```

Comment: **P.S.** *I am not allowed to import any Java packages* -> Do you know, that `java.lang` package is imported by default :-)

Comment: _I am not allowed to import any additional Java packages._ -> Just edited, thanks for the comment!

Comment: In `getNumActions()` why do you call  `i = getNumActions()`? That's not what I was asking for. The reason why I put it into my answer was purely because it was intended to be used similarly to a LinkedList.size() variable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, then each time you call `getAction(int)`, call it like this:

`getAction((some size variable) - index)` (I would recommend giving your `Node`s a length or size variable)

Instead of this

`getAction(some size variable)`

In a for loop, you can also do `for(int i=(some size variable)-1; i>=0; i--)` to start from the end.

Comment: Both of the options you provided do not work:
- First option gives me an error saying "Cannot resolve method getAction()" when replaced with  `getAction(index)` in the main method.
- Second option gives me infinite errors saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Comment: I'd like to see these modified programs.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the code on the very bottom. Full code is at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is off topic, but I think that using **recursion** to count elements in a `LinkedList` is a quite complex solution.

I think you should split two logical objects in your program first:

- `LinkedList` implementation with basic methods like `getSize()`, `add(String)` and `remove(String)`;
- `ActionManager` implementation with methods like `doAction(Stirng)`, `undo(String)` and `redo(String)`.

In this case, you have a better quality of your program and bug-free.

---

```
public final class LinkedList {

    private Node head;
    private int size;

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void add(String value) {
        Node node = new Node(value);

        if (size == 0)
            head = node;
        else {
            Node tail = getTail();
            tail.next = node;
            node.prev = tail;
        }

        size++;
    }

    public String remove() {
        if (size == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        String value;

        if (size == 1) {
            value = head.value;
            head = null;
        } else {
            Node tail = getTail();
            value = tail.value;
            tail.prev.next = null;
            tail.prev = null;
        }

        size--;
        return value;
    }

    private Node getTail() {
        Node node = head;

        while (node != null && node.next != null)
            node = node.next;

        return node;
    }

    private static final class Node {

        private final String value;
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;

        public Node(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public final class ActionManager {

    private final LinkedList actions = new LinkedList();
    private final LinkedList undoActions = new LinkedList();

    public int getTotalActions() {
        return actions.getSize();
    }

    public void doAction(String action) {
        actions.add(action);
    }

    public void undo() {
        if (actions.getSize() == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        undoActions.add(actions.remove());
    }

    public void redo() {
        if (undoActions.getSize() == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        actions.add(undoActions.remove());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "total: " + actions.getSize() + ", undo: " + undoActions.getSize();
    }

}
```